# How can i access scope in angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I have two controllers

```
app.controller('TestCtrl1', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.save = function () {
        console.log("TestCtrl1 - myMethod");
    }
}]);



 app.controller('TestCtrl2', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
$scope.var1 = 'test1'        

$scope.save = function () {
            console.log("TestCtrl1 - myMethod");
    }
}]);
```

Then i have two services

```
.service('Service1', function($q) {
    return {
        save: function(obj) {
       }
    }
})

.service('Service2', function($q) {
    return {
        save: function(obj) {
       }
    }
})
```

1. For my 60% of stuff i just call `save` on ctrl1 which then called service save method
2. Now There are cases where before saving i need to do some stuff like chnaging some object parameters different than genral case there i check e,g

   ```
   if(model == 'User'){
   //Here i do this (sample of code)
       var service = $injector.get('Service2');
       service.save()
   ```

Now my problem is in Service 2 i need access to `var1`. How can i do that

Comment: `$rootScope` is one way to do it. and passing it would be another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the service(s) itself to share the variable as part of the service object as well as methods of each service

```
.service('Service2', function($q) {
    var self = this;
    this.var1 = 'test1';
    this.save = function(obj) {            
    }

});

app.controller('TestCtrl2', ['$scope','Service1','Service2', function ($scope, Service1, Service2, ) {
     // bind scope variable to service property
     $scope.var1 = Service2.var1;       
     // add a service method to scope
     $scope.save = Service1.save;
     // now call that service method
     $scope.save( $scope.var1 );
}]);
```

You can also inject a service into another service if needed

Comment: But those variables are bound to scope of controller . Suppose var is the current active menu. Now that means i also need to update Service as well with active menu

Comment: Is it ok if i watch those variables in controller and on chnage i update service variables.  is this the way people do things. Currently i did that but i am not sure if thats the right way

Comment: With proper object binding you often don't need a watch but using one is not uncommon

Answer (score 0):

injecting services into other services (one possible method) :

html:

```
<div id="div1" ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <!--to confirm that the services are working-->
     <p>service three: {{serviceThree}}</p>  

</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])

.service('s1', function() {
    this.value = 3;
})

.service('s2', function() {
    this.value = 10;
})

.service('s3', function(s1,s2) {     //other services as dependencies
    this.value = s1.value+s2.value;  //13   

})
.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $injector) {  //$injector is a dependency

    $scope.serviceThree = $injector.get('s3').value; //using the injector

});
```

here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ueo9ck8r/